# How to run bash script in upstart conf file?

Tags: bash, scripts, upstart

I made bash script "kvm_manage". How should I write .conf script and run my bash script inside? It is possible?

I am beginner..

Answer (score 1):

There are several great tutorials available for you to create upstart jobs.

Here you go

- http://upstart.ubuntu.com/getting-started.html
- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpstartHowto
- http://digital-madness.in/blog/2013/ubuntu-12-04-upstart-at-boot-services/

Comment: The third link is not very accurate. `/etc/init.d` is used by SysV, not Upstart. Upstart uses `.conf` files in `/etc/init`. While Ubuntu provides legacy support for SysV, these directories shouldn't be confused as they are utilized by different service handlers. It is also worth noting that Ubuntu 15.04 has ditched Upstart and gone back to using SysV.